# I’m trying to identify an anthology of short stories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

There are only a few bits of different stories I remember:

- One was about two men, one being a dwarf. They would go on coaches and the dwarf would hide in the suitcase and then steal people’s possessions.
- Another story from this book was about a man who worked in a morgue. His girlfriend would always want to be there with him until she got caught by her boyfriend, who then proceeded to lock them both in the freezer until they were found the next day.
- Another story involved an invisible man who would go into people's houses.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Roughly when did you read this anthology, and when you think it might've been published?

Comment: My dad used to read me story’s from this anthology book when I was younger so I’d say around 2007-2010. And it wasn’t a necessarily old book but I couldn’t tell you when it had been published.

Comment: "man who worked in a morgue" ... "his girlfriend" ... "her boyfriend" ... are three separate people? There's a love triangle; she has 2 boyfriends?

Comment: Yes exactly her boyfriend caught them in the morgue.